# Why does my user get logged out when navigating to a new page (next.js/firebase auth using react context)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm pretty new to React/Next.js and Firebase, and I'm having an issue where after a user signs-in using firebase authentication, if I refresh the page or navigate to a new URL, the user gets signed out.

I have a navbar component where I'm trying to display different things whether the user is logged in or not, and I believe I'm using firebase client side authentication and react context to provide the user object to all components in my Next app, and am using a useAuth hook (https://usehooks.com/useAuth/). Here's my code for the useAuth hook, which is pretty much copied from that link:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import firebase from './firebase';
import { createUser } from './db';

const authContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const auth = useProvideAuth();
    return <authContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</authContext.Provider>;
}

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(authContext);
};

function useProvideAuth() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const handleUser = (rawUser) => {
        if (rawUser) {
            const user = formatUser(rawUser);
            createUser(user.uid, user);
            setUser(user);
            return user;
        } else {
            setUser(false);
            return false;
        }
    };

    const signinWithGoogle = (redirect) => {
        return firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log('before sign with google then statement');
                handleUser(response.user);
                // console.log('after sign with google then statement');
                if (redirect) {
                    Router.push(redirect);
                }
            });
    };

    const signout = (redirect) => {
        return firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => {
                handleUser(false);
                if (redirect) {
                    Router.push(redirect);
                }
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
            console.log('called');
            handleUser;
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    return {
        user,
        signinWithGoogle,
        signout,
    };
}

const formatUser = (user) => {
    return {
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.displayName,
        provider: user.providerData[0].providerId,
        photoUrl: user.photoURL,
    };
};
```

And this is how I call my hook in my Navbar component:

```js
export default function Navbar() {
    const auth = useAuth();

    const user = auth.user;
  ...
```

When I sign-in, it works as expected at first, but if I navigate to a new page or refresh the current page, the user becomes null and I'm assuming that means they got logged out somehow. Apologies if this is a trivial question or misunderstanding as I'm pretty new to all of this :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `handleUser(user)` inside the `useEffect`? Otherwise the user will not be set when mounting.

Comment: @juliomalves you're totally right, I'm not sure how I missed that! I actually just changed the useEffect code to 
___
`const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(handleUser); return () => unsubscribe();`
___
and it seemed to work instead of also having to add handleUser(user). I'm pretty new to useEffect, so I'm a little confused on why this would work. Doesn't this only return a cleanup function for when the component unmounts? I'm not sure why it fixed my issue.

Comment: Passing the `handleUser` directly into the `onAuthStateChanged` callback will call that function directly (passing the `user` to it) when the callback happens. Essentially, does the same as my suggestion with a shorter syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I get that passing handleUser as a callback will call that function, but doesn't that only run when the component unmounts? I may be wrong but I thought returning a function in useEffect only runs that when the component unmounts, which is why I'm not sure how it would enable my user to persist when the page is refreshed or when navigating to a new page.

Comment: `unsubscribe` gets called during unmount, but `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` gets called during mount.

Comment: isnt the code assigning the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` function to the variable `unsubscribe`, which is only called by useEffect when the component unmounts because of the return? How would `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` get called during mount? Also, thank you again so much for the help!

Comment: When the `useEffect`  runs the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` will get called too. `unsubscribe` is simply a reference to the listener that gets created from that call. During unmount `unsubscribe` is then called to remove that listener.